# VBA: Filtering files from Scripting.FileSystemObject with parameters like date and time

Tags: vba, excel, file-handling

I am trying to write a code to find the list of XML files in a location, but the location has too many files and folder, so i wrote a code to get the list of xml files from the location to excel workbook, but i am unable to set the filter to get the files, for example ***i want to get the list of files created in year 2015***. Some one please help me on this, find the code below.

```
    Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath, IncludeSubfolders)
    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each myFile In mySource.Files        
        If InStr(1, myFile.Name, ".xml", vbBinaryCompare) Then        
            Worksheets("Filelist").Range("A6").Offset(x, 0) = myFile.Path 'Replace(myFile.Path, myFile.Name, "")                      
            x = x + 1
            End If
        Else
            Resume
        End If        
    Next
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
            Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True)
        Next
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: how about utilizing the file attributes like e.g. DateCreated? You'd could store those information in additional columns and build filters as required. Or you can just check the information of the files when you are already looping through them..

Comment: yes this will be helpful, i tried them with date modified and date created information's its working. is that is the only way by using loop to check all the files, now my question is is there any other efficient way to complete it quickly. for example if i have 100,000 files should i have to loop all of them. because it take much time to complete.

Answer (score 2):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6a7czx(v=vs.84).aspx

```
Function ShowFileInfo(filespec)
   Dim fso, f
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.GetFile(filespec)
   ShowFileInfo = "Created: " & f.DateCreated
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a whirl:

```
Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath)

files = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("DIR """ & mySourcePath  & _
    IIf(Right(mySourcePath, 1) = "\", "", "\") & _
    "*.xml"" /T:C /S /B /A:-D /O:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

For Each fil In files
    If Year(CDate(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(CStr(fil)).DateCreated)) = 2015 Then
        Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = CStr(fil)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

This uses the `DIR` command in cmd.exe to list all the `.xml` files and then uses FileSystemObject to check the date created. If they were created in 2015 then it lists them in Column A.

Comment: Is there any any efficient way to complete it quick if i have more than 100000 files?

Comment: The only way you can do this is by looping, whichever method you go for - there is no native way to _only_ display files created in a certain year through VBA. Using CMD is probably faster than FSO for getting the inital list of files

Comment: There may be a WinAPI that you can use - but again, you would still have to loop